# Angular Table Multiple Input Text box shows same value

Tags: angular

Language - Angular 4

I have an angular table, which has multiple rows. Each row has a text box in the last column. When I enter the values in a textbox in one of the rows, all other textboxes in other rows also gets updated with the value.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Invoice Number</th>
                                            <th>Invoice Amount</th>
                                            <th>Amount Due</th>
                                            <th>Payment</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr *ngFor="let row of invoices_items">
                                            <td>{{row.date}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.invoice_number}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.total}}</td>
                                            <td>{{row.amount_due}}</td>
                                            <td class="text-right col-md-2">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payreported" name="payreported" 
                                                [(ngModel)]="newpayrec.payreported" (blur)="checkamount()"
                                                placeholder="Enter Payment Amt.">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Component.ts

```
declare interface newpayrec {
   vendorname?: string;
   amount?:string;
   paydate?:string;
   paymode?:string;
   depositto?:string;   
   invoicedate?:string; 
   payreported?:string;
}
..............
.............

ngOnInit(){

    this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

    this.newpayrec={
        vendorname:'',
        amount:'',
        paydate:'',
        paymode:'',
        depositto:'',
        payreported:''
    }

this.http.get('/api/xyz/'+this.userId)
  .subscribe(result=>{
        this.vendors = result.json().data;
    }, err =>{
      console.log('error in api');          
    }, () => {
        console.log('api executed successfully');  
    }        
    });
}
```

I want only the particular textbox to have the values(the textbox where I enter the value) instead of all the rows in the table getting updated. How do I achieve this? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

This grief is usually caused by the name directive while using *ngFor. For some weird reason the name gets the same reference for all the rows. Hence you should use the index of each row and append it to the name.

In your ngFor, append the index expression 'let i = index'. Also append the name of input with "-{{i}}"

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of invoices_items;let i = index">
  <td>{{row.date}}</td>
  <td>{{row.invoice_number}}</td>
  <td>{{row.total}}</td>
  <td>{{row.amount_due}}</td>
  <td class="text-right col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payreported" name="payreported-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="row.payreported" (blur)="checkamount()"                                                  placeholder="Enter Payment Amt.">
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

because you have `newpayrec.payreported` single instance. and you are using same for all row. also you are used [(ngModel)] as two way binding so value populated.
you need different instance of every row.

for ex.

`invoices_items` is array of objects.
so you need to added specific key `payreported` or `newpayrec` object into row before this loop.
so you can use it like `[(ngModel)]="row.payreported"` or `[(ngModel)]="row.newpayrec.payreported"`

ex with single key

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of invoices_items">
  <td>{{row.date}}</td>
  <td>{{row.invoice_number}}</td>
  <td>{{row.total}}</td>
  <td>{{row.amount_due}}</td>
  <td class="text-right col-md-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payreported" name="payreported" [(ngModel)]="row.payreported" (blur)="checkamount()"                                                  placeholder="Enter Payment Amt.">
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your example code and my code? I couldn't see any diff. can you plz clarify.

Comment: Read first paragraph please. you passing [(ngModel)]="newpayrec.payreported" and i said [(ngModel)]="row.newpayrec.payreported" or [(ngModel)]="row.payreported". and row coming from loop